# Symfony2 + Doctrine MongoDM document generation issue

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, symfony

I'm trying to generate getters/setters for my Doctrine Mongo document class.

The document code looks something like this:

```
namespace MySite\GameBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

use MySite\GameBundle\Document\User;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Game {
    /**
     * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="User")
     */
    protected $user;

    /** @Date */
    protected $start_time;

}
```

However, when I attempt to generate the getters and setters using the `CLI command php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents SiteGameBundle`, I get the following back:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                      
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@ReferenceOne" in property Site\GameBundle\Document\Game::$user was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

This one has me stumped, because from a namespace perspective I think I have everything properly included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You imported doctrine annotation as `MongoDB` namespace. So you should use `@MongoDB\ReferenceOne`, like `@MongoDB\Document`.